# converting a string to a constant string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code...

```
Const ToAddress As String = username.Text & "@gmail.com"
```

which sets to ToAddress to be used in on my Net.Mail.MailMessage
that is to be created with the following constructor

`Dim mm As New Net.Mail.MailMessage(username.Text, ToAddress`)

which takes in a string and a constant string. But I get an error here

```
Const ToAddress As String = **username.Text** & "@gmail.com"
```

that says : constant expression required

Answer (score 2):

[how to use mailmessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.to.aspx)

username.text is variable, you wont be able to create a const

you can always create a function that would do validation on the username.text

```
 public function ToAddress(byval _username as string) as MailAddress
      '
      'validation here for _username
      '
      return new MailAddress(_username & "@gmail.com")         
 end function
```

Comment: If I change the ToAddress to a string the MailMessage constructor does not take it. I need to set the address dynamically. Is there any work around?

Comment: @Kwah, look at my first line for a link to how to use it

Answer (score 0):

That is not how a Const should be used.  See the [first line here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const). "a constant is a special kind of variable whose value cannot be altered during program execution"

Edit: See Fredou's answer for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET and C# are not C. Constant modifier is just used for constants whose values are known at the time of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a constant is a value that is compiled as a literal into the assembly by the compiler.  This is why you cannot define constants as an expression because the compiler cannot evaluate the expression at compilation time.

When you define a constant the compiler takes the value of that constant and replaces all uses of the constant in your source with the literal value.  In your example I don't see any reason why you would need to define your string as `Const` since the method receiving the string will have no way of determining if the string was a `Const` at compilation time.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a way to send users a mail on asp.net 2.0.

Comment: The phrase "...cannot define constants as an expression..." isn't quite true. You can define a constant as an expression IF all terms of that expression are literals or other constants.

Comment: @RolandTumble: Excellent distinction!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Const, specifically, if you just want the "constant" behavior for the life of an instance of your class, try:

```
ReadOnly ToAddress As String = username.Text & "@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Even though the MailMessage constructor does take ReadOnly instead of Const for the second argument two other issues arrise...
1. ReadOnly cannot be used inside a Sub 
2. username.txt is not visible outside...requires a sub of the ffg format Sub subname(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Comment: I must misunderstand what you mean by (1) -- the following code is valid:
Class someclass
    Private Sub SomeMethod(ByVal SomeArg As String)
        ReadOnly ToAddress As String = SomeArg & "@gmail.com"
    End Sub
End Class

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance. I closed visual studio and restarted it and now it's sending mail works fine. Seems like VS has a bug...